# TypeError: listingsRef.add is not a function. (In 'listingsRef.add(updatedUploadObjects)', 'listingsRef.add' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a listing app, and using firebase as my back end, before I add .orderBy statement to sort the data by creating date, everyting works fine and I can update new post on the app, but after I add .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc') in the listing, I can not update any new post and there is a error
**"TypeError: listingsRef.add is not a function. (In 'listingsRef.add(updatedUploadObjects)', 'listingsRef.add' is undefined)**
the code is shown below:

```
    import { setFavoriteItems } from '../../../favorites/redux'
import { firebase } from '../../../api/firebase/config'
import ServerConfiguration from '../../../../ServerConfiguration'

const savedListingsRef = firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection(ServerConfiguration.database.collection.SAVED_LISTINGS)
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
const listingsRef = firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection(ServerConfiguration.database.collection.LISTINGS)
  .orderBy('createdAt','desc')
const ListingCategoriesRef = firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection(ServerConfiguration.database.collection.CATEGORIES)
  .orderBy('order')
```

and this:

```
 if (selectedItem) {
    listingsRef
      .doc(selectedItem.id)
      .update({ ...updatedUploadObjects, photo: coverPhoto })
      .then(docRef => {
        callback({ success: true })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        callback({ success: false })
      })
  } else {
    listingsRef
      .add(updatedUploadObjects)
      .then(docRef => {
        if (docRef.id) {
          listingsRef
            .doc(docRef.id)
            .update({ id: docRef.id, photo: coverPhoto })
        }
        callback({ success: true })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        callback({ success: false })
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: That's **a lot** of code you shared there. Are you sure this is the [**minimum** needed to reproduce this problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for your replying! I have minimum the code now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This defines a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference):

```
const savedListingsRef = firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection(ServerConfiguration.database.collection.SAVED_LISTINGS)
```

If you check that link, you'll see that a `CollectionReference` has an `add` method, meaning that you can add a document to it.

---

This defines a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query):

```
const savedListingsRef = firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection(ServerConfiguration.database.collection.SAVED_LISTINGS)
  .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
```

If you check that last link, you'll see that a query doesn't have an `add` method, so you can't `add` something to a query.

---

You'll want to keep the `CollectionReference` around too, so that you can call `add()` on that.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your reply!    I am new to react and after I see your answer, I still have a question: The second code you showd me is a query but I find the only different between the first one and the second one is I add .orderBy statement. So how to change it from query to collection?   Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I understand because orderBy returns a query so I can't add data in it, but how to change the query to CollectionReference?